# Strange problem with rc.local not running some commands

Tags: boot, scripts, startup

I have Ubuntu 16.04. I am trying to run commands in `/etc/rc.local`, but they are not running correctly. I have enabled `rc.local` using `sudo systemctl enable rc-local.service`. I can see `rc.local` has run and the exit value using `sudo systemctl status rc-local.service`. I can change the exit value and can see the change in the systemctl status, so I know `rc.local` is running. Here are the commands.

```bash
sudo echo updatetime >> /home/admin/log.txt
sudo /home/admin/updatetime.sh
sudo date >> /home/admin/log.txt
```

Nothing is added to my log file. My time is not updated. I can run the script from terminal using `sudo /home/admin/updatetime.sh` and the time will update. I have checked all the file permissions and everything is readable, executable and writable. Please help. I'm at a complete loss for why I can't get this to work.

Comment: Commands in `rc.local` are run as `root` so `sudo` is inappropriate here (and may be causing issues since sudo doesn't like running without a tty)

Comment: I remove the `sudo` from rc.local, and problem remains :(